# Can I ask Intellij to apply intention actions for the whole line?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, I can ask Intellij Idea to apply the intention action for the code under the caret. For example, if the cursor is on a class name and I have not yet imported the class, it will allow me to import the class.

Is there a way to do the same if I am somewhere else on the line (like using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> in eclipse) ? Or maybe there is a shortcut to go to the next problem ?

Comment: For me `F2` jumps to the next problem

Comment: @Vic: that's useful thanks

Comment: I'm using 15, and it will allow you to `Alt+Enter` from anywhere even if your caret isn't on the actual problem.  Just give it a second to detect the problem and solve it for you, and the prompt will appear above the problem.

Comment: Actually yes @Franck you're right... Don't know what happened before